# Getting JRE error when trying to Uninstall OpManager

Tags: java, uninstall, software-uninstall, jre

Hey I'm kinda new to Ubuntu so forgive the basic nature of the doubt. I'm getting the following error when I try to uninstall OpManager by running uninstaller.bin.

> This application requires a Java Run Time Environment (JRE)    to
>   run. Searching for one on your computer was not successful.    Please
>   use the command line switch -is:javahome to specify     a valid JRE. 
>   For more help use the option -is:help.

I have JRE installed and I'm pretty sure the path variables are present for it.

Please help.